# The GET request to make must change with button ID clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, git, api

I am new to JQUERY and AJAX.
I need to make a get request to the git search api based on the topic the user chooses, i.e. if the user chooses clicks the button named ruby, I want to make a request to git for the top 10 python apis, similarly if he clicks a button named php i want to display repos of php.

To achieve this i created 2 ajax functions and called the respective ajax function at the button click.

```
<button  id="ruby" onclick="startAjax();"   class="btn btn-outline-dark">Java</button>
<button  id="php"  onclick="startAjax1();"    class="btn btn-outline-dark">ios</button>
```

then,

```
function startAjax(){
                $.ajax({

                    headers:{ "Content-Type":"application/json","Accept": "application/json"},
                    type:'GET',
                    url:'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repos+topic:ruby&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10',  }); 

 function startAjax1(){
                $.ajax({

                    headers:{ "Content-Type":"application/json","Accept": "application/json"},
                    type:'GET',
                    url:'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repos+topic:ios&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10',});
```

This requires me to write as many ajax calls as buttons are there, is there a better way to do this? Can i use the id of the button and change the get url accordingly?

Thank you:)

Comment: No neeed to set Content-Type header for GET request....there is no content sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you always have to do is to look what are the differences in a function, what is variable. Everything variable should be - you guessed it - a variable. :-)

So in your case, it would be simple to use the id (or a data-attribute). To do this, try something like

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repos+topic:' + $(this).attr(“id”) + '&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10',
  }).then(s => console.log(s));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ruby" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Java</button>
<button id="php" class="btn btn-outline-dark">ios</button>
```

Also, don't use inline javascript. Better assign a proper event listener and handler like demonstrated above.

Comment: I tried $(this).id but the request utl shows undefined:                   https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repos+topic:undefined&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10

Comment: Sorry, missed the attr(). Try again please. @AbhilashGopalakrishna

Comment: You might need to rewrite the “ from my answer, I’m on mobile and it creates wrong ones.... @AbhilashGopalakrishna

Comment: Thank you this works :). I am learning JQUERY and AJAX now, it is possible to find jquery methods and what they do in the documentation. But, the this selector and it being applied as such I wasnt able to find or rather I did not know where to look. Is there a source that can help with this. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

Use data attributes

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark ajax-button" data-url="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repos+topic:ruby&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10">Ruby</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark ajax-button" data-url="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=repos+topic:ios&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10">ios</button>
```

Then send the data attribute to a single function.

```
function startAjax(url){
    $.ajax({
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: url
    }); 

$(document)ready(function(){
    $(".ajax-button").click(function(event){
        var url = $(event.target).data("url");
        startAjax(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate so much code, also not for the whole url that differs only by a single thing

Comment: It's not duplicated code, just two very similar string values.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this ajax delegation logic to implement jquery/ajax unless I need more control over the request queue, in which case I'll use the `$.when.apply()` method posted below.

As far as your question about different URL's for different buttons, you can use the `data` attribute on the button element to store the URL's and access via the jquery `.data()` function.

**Ajax Delegation**

```
(function($){
    $(function(){


        //Usage Example

        var inputString = $("#myInput").val();
        var inputNumber = $("#myInteger").val();
        var data = {inputString: inputString, inputNumber : inputNumber};

        $('parent').on('click', 'button', delegateAjax('js/myAjax.php', data, 'POST');

    });

    function delegateAjax(url, data, responseType, dataType, callback) {

        function successHandler() {
            console.log("Ajax Success");
        };

        function failureHandler(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("Ajax Error");
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
            console.dir(xhr);
        };

        function handler404(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("404 Error");
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
            console.dir(xhr);
        };

        function handler500(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("500 Error");
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
            console.dir(xhr); 
        };

        url = typeof url !== 'undefined' ? url : 'js/ajaxDefault.php';
        data = typeof data !== 'undefined' ? data : new Object();
        responseType = typeof responseType !== 'undefined' ? responseType : 'GET';
        dataType = typeof dataType !== 'undefined' ? dataType : 'json';
        callback = typeof callback !== 'undefined' ? callback : 'callback';

        var jqxhr = $.ajax({url: url, type: responseType, cache: true, data: data, dataType: dataType, jsonp: callback, 
                            statusCode: { 404: handler404, 500: handler500 }});
        jqxhr.done(successHandler);
        jqxhr.fail(failureHandler);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Ajax Request Queue**

```
//Set this var to max requests in queue.
var ajaxMax = 5;

var ajaxActive = 0;
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  ajaxActive++;
  document.ajaxRunning = ajaxActive > 0;
  document.ajaxQueueFull = ajaxActive > ajaxMax;
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  ajaxActive--;
  document.ajaxRunning = ajaxActive > 0;
  document.ajaxQueueFull = ajaxActive > ajaxMax;
}

var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'someurl',
    success: function(result){}
});

while(request === null && (request.readyState < 1 || request.readyState > 4)) {
    if (document.ajaxQueueFull) {
      //abort existing requests
      $.each(request as v) {
         v.abort();
      }
    }
    pendingAjax.push(request);
}


$.when.apply($, pendingAjax).done( successCallback ).fail( failCallback)
```